# Website user's can't access the shop in Odoo.(Showing Forbidden)

Tags: web, odoo-9

These are the following steps I have done already but still getting this 403 Forbidden Error in Odoo community version.
In the general settings 
1)Checked "Allow external users to sign up" and select Template User for "Template user for new users created through signup"
2)Checked "Activate the customer portal"
3)For the Template User checked as 
"public"
There is another  button in Product module and Also in User module which is called "Published on Website" I have already clicked as published. But Still getting this 403 forbidden error.Please help what else I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

I will explain:

1. Go to setting -> users
2. Erase search default filter, use advanced search, and select Active is false, then push apply, then it will show Template User
3. Edit template user, check boxes public, and portal access
4. Save user
5. Logout
6. Shop already is shown for guest customers